# How to replace multiple random characters in string with underscore(_) in PHP

Tags: php, replace

I am using codes like "gjhyYhK", "HJjhkeuJ" etc. But want user to show these codes like:

gj_y__K

HJj__e_J

means code will be edited with "_" at random positions in code.

Comment: what percentage of characters do you want to replace?

Comment: priyanka show what you have tried?? put your code as well

Comment: Hi pala! I want to remove 40% characters.

Comment: thanks for that - answer tested and provided

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you want:

```
  $str = "gjhyYhK";

  $len = strlen($str);
  $num_to_remove = ceil($len * .4); // 40% removal
  for($i = 0; $i < $num_to_remove; $i++)
  {
    $k = 0;
    do
    {
      $k = rand(1, $len);
    } while($str[$k-1] == "_");
    $str[$k-1] = "_";
  }
  print $str . "\n";
```

If you want more underscores, change the value of `$underscores`.  This will guarantee you get how many underscores you want, so long as you want fewer than the length of the string

Answer (score 0):

you can try below code to get the functionality what you are looking for

```
<?php
$string = "gjhyYhK";
$percentage = 40;
$total_length = strlen($string);
$number_of_underscore = floor(($percentage / 100) * $total_length); // I have use floor value, you can use ceil() as well
for ($i = 1; $i <= $number_of_underscore; $i++)
{
    $random_position = rand(0, strlen($string) - 1); // get the random position of character to be replaced
    if (substr($string, $random_position, 1) !== '_') // check if its already replaced underscore (_)
    {
        $string = preg_replace("/" . (substr($string, $random_position, 1)) . "/", '_', $string, 1); // here preg_replaced use to replace the character only once,  (i.e str_replace() will replace all matching characters)
    }
    else
    {
        $i--; // else decrement $i for the loop to run one more time
    }
}
echo $string;
?>
```

let me know if any other help needed

Comment: You are changing the length of the string - all the characters are still there, in the same order. just with underscores between them

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$string=array(
    'gjhyYhK',
    'HJjhkeuJ'
);
$arr=array();
foreach ($string as $key=>$value) {
    $arr[$key]='';
    for ($i=1; $i <=strlen($value); $i++) {
        if(rand(0,1)){
            $arr[$key].=substr($string[$key],$i,1);
        }else{
            $arr[$key].='_';
        }
    }
}
var_dump($arr);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$str = "ADFJ";
$strlen = strlen($str);
$newStr = '';
for ($i = 0; $i < $strlen; $i++) {
    if ($i == rand(0, $strlen)) {
        $newStr .= '_';
    } else {
        $newStr .= $str[$i];
    }
}
echo $newStr;
```

Comment: AD_FJ,ADF_J,A_D_FJ this is what i am getting

Comment: run it some more. you'll see what i mean. not to mention you're not actually replacing any of the characters, just stretching the string out

Comment: Can you try now., Edited the answer

Comment: a) i didnt upvote anything. b) the other answers are wrong. they still are.